# Defining lumped and distributed elements according to signal travel time

Tags: lumped

We define distributed elements as circuit elements where the physical dimensions of the elements cannot be ignored and the differential equations stating the current, voltage etc also contain a variable signifying physical size. Fair enough.

My book goes on to describe that the travel time of the electrical signal through the element cannot be ignored in distributed elements.
 But we are not talking about astronomical distances here! In what sense can we practically classify lumped and distributed elements on the basis of time, when for all practical purposes, the electrical signal will travel instantaneously through the circuit element?

Comment: You can get logic gates with a 100 ps rise time, during which time light travels 3 cm.  "Astronomical distances" for such a device would be on the order of a few millimeters.  Put something like that on a PCB and everything connected to it becomes a distributed element because the time scale is so short.

Comment: @user1850479 Thanks!

Comment: Instead of thinking about travel time, think about wavelength: When the length of the path is significant relative to the wavelength of the signal, which happens first with the shortest wavelengths in the signal which is the highest frequency component of the signal. When this happens the voltage and current conditions between both ends of the line can be at different values (ie. the signal can no longer be assumed to be traveling instantaneously down the line). Beyond that, how much is too much depends on what your system can tolerate: 1/4 wavelength, 1/10th wavelength, 1/100th wavelength etc

Comment: See my answer about relative "errors" when you use "line" or "lumped section". https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/596660/why-do-we-need-to-use-transmission-line-theory/596735#596735 Nota: <<<the electrical signal will travel instantaneously through the circuit element? >>> This is not true. There is always a finite "time travel" or "time transit", as low it can be.

Comment: See the "travelling wave tube" in the microwave and how "transit time" can be used for amplifying some fast signals ....   Used also in "distributed solid state amplifiers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My book goes on to describe that the travel time of the electrical
> signal through the element cannot be ignored in distributed elements.*

That is true.

> *But we are not talking about astronomical distances here!*

What about a 1 metre length of 50 Ω coax? It's not astronomically big but, if we don't respect the thing as a transmission-line then we get problems.

> *In what
> sense can we practically classify lumped and distributed elements on
> the basis of time, when for all practical purposes, the electrical
> signal will travel instantaneously through the circuit element?*

No, it won't travel instantaneously; the speed will be somewhat close to the speed of light but that isn't instantaneous. Neither is it instantaneous in the 1 metre of coax I mentioned earlier and we use coax at much much longer lengths than 1 metre.

If we don't terminate the coax in proper components we might get this happening: -

<sub>V1 produces a 1 volt step after 50 ns and remains high. T2 is a 1 metre long transmission line of \$Z_0\$= 50 Ω</sub>

[image]

[image]

When we should be getting something more like this if we terminated the cable correctly: -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> when for all practical purposes, the electrical signal will travel instantaneously through the circuit element?

It won't. The speed of light is about 1 foot (30 cm) per nanosecond. When dielectric materials like FR-4 get involved it might be only 1/2 or 2/3 that.

So if your circuit is in the range of 10-30 cm in diameter (the largest physical dimension of the circuit), and you have operating frequencies in the 10's or 100's of MHz, then the electrical signal cannot travel instantaneously across your circuit for the practical purpose of operating or analyzing your circuit.

As a rough guideline, when the diameter of the circuit is more than 1/10 of the wavelength of the highest frequency signal present in the circuit, you should start to worry about distributed circuit effects. If you are doing precision work, you might want to start at 1/20 wavelength.